# Groovy: parsing XML and storing attribute values to variables

Tags: groovy

I have to read an XML and store the attribute values into a variable. As I am new to Groovy I am getting it difficult. So far this is what I have done.

PS: This is what i am doing inside a method.

```
XmlParser parser = new XmlParser()
//def xmldata1 = parser.parse (new FileInputStream("c:\\temp\\create.xml"))

def xml = """<record_change>
<record_id>04707317-28e3-40cb-a227-15d2c91e08c2</record_id> 
<incident number="201507-001" status="open"/> 
</record_change>"""

def xmldata1 = parser.parseText(xml)
def n_id = xmldata1.record_id.?????
def n_number = ????? //expecting incident number
def m_status = ????? // expecting incident status
```

Could someone help me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The short answer is the following:

```
def n_id     = xmldata1.record_id[0].text()
def n_number = xmldata1.incident[0].@number
def m_status = xmldata1.incident[0].@status
```

Note this differs slightly from Jayan's answer because of the indexing of the nodelist to an individual node. In your case it's not a problem for `n_id`, but you'll need the indices for `n_number` and `m_status` otherwise they are lists. Also, if you get data where there's more than one Node in the NodeList, you'll get problems. See the `text()` example later in my answer.

For this type of investigation, your best bet is using `groovysh`, and then directly interrogating the objects.

Here's a session showing this in action:

```
groovy:000> p = new XmlParser()
===> groovy.util.XmlParser@292ea3d5

groovy:000> xml = '<record_change><record_id>04707317-28e3-40cb-a227-15d2c91e08c2</record_id><incident number="201507-001" status="open"/></record_change>'
===> <record_change><record_id>04707317-28e3-40cb-a227-15d2c91e08c2</record_id><incident number="201507-001" status="open"/></record_change>

groovy:000> d = p.parseText(xml)
===> record_change[attributes={}; value=[record_id[attributes={}; value=[04707317-28e3-40cb-a227-15d2c91e08c2]], incident[attributes={number=201507-001, status=open}; value=[]]]]
```

Now we have the parsed xml, and it's in a local variable `d`. You can already see from the toString() some of the parts it has broken it up into.

The returned `d` is a [`groovy.util.Node`](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/util/Node.html):

```
groovy:000> d.getClass()
===> class groovy.util.Node
```

`d.record_id` is a [`groovy.util.NodeList`](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/util/NodeList.html):

```
groovy:000> d.record_id.getClass()
===> class groovy.util.NodeList
```

A NodeList has a [`text()`](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/util/NodeList.html#text()) method on it, which "Returns the textual representation of the current node and all its child nodes." There should be ringing bells now. The last part says "... and all its child nodes". There's also a `text()` method on Node, so if you want to be certain not to get additional children, then index the NodeList:

```
groovy:000> d.record_id[0].text()
===> 04707317-28e3-40cb-a227-15d2c91e08c2
```

If you had something like:

```
<record_change>
    <record_id>1111</record_id>
    <record_id>2222</record_id>
</record_change>
```

Then calling text() on just record_id would give:

```
groovy:000> d.record_id.text()
===> 11112222
```

which probably isn't what you want. Be very careful if you're working on a Node or a NodeList. If you know you only have one node in the list, then you'll be fine.

For the `incident`, you find it also is a NodeList, but obviously has no text part, just attributes, as we can see from the toString() of it:

```
 groovy:000> d.incident
 ===> [incident[attributes={number=201507-001, status=open}; value=[]]]
```

The `text()` method returns the part in `value=[]`. But here we have attributes which are accessible using the `@attributeName` syntax. First, we can also use the function [`attributes()`](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/util/Node.html#attributes()) to interrogate their names and values (it returns a regular Map). This is a function on Node, not NodeList, so we have to index the NodeList with `d.incident[0]` to get the Node from the NodeList. Thus we have:

```
groovy:000> d.incident[0].attributes()
===> [number:201507-001, status:open]

groovy:000> d.incident[0].attributes().keySet()
===> [number, status]
```

Directly, you can get the attributes like this:

```
groovy:000> d.incident.@number
===> [201507-001]
```

Ah! we have invoked `@number` on the NodeList, so it returns a List of the values (a single one in your case, but if you have more complex data it'll be multiple items). If you want the individual value on its own, index the appropriate element of the NodeList as previously done:

```
groovy:000> d.incident[0].@number
===> 201507-001
```

So be careful with indexing to get the individual Node element.

Finally, if you are referencing elements with hyphens in them, you can use quotes around it to get a value, e.g. `d.'some-element'[0].text()`.

Comment: this could be a reference answer. Nothing more to add to it.

Comment: thanks @Jayan, this is actually how I learnt how to use groovy's xml parsing too many moons ago.

Answer (score 2):

- Use "@attributename" for getting attribute values
- Use "element" name to get to element.

Here is your example:

```
XmlParser parser = new XmlParser()
//def xmldata1 = parser.parse (new FileInputStream("c:\\temp\\create.xml"))

def xml = """<record_change>
<record_id>04707317-28e3-40cb-a227-15d2c91e08c2</record_id>
<incident number="201507-001" status="open"/>
</record_change>"""

def xmldata1 = parser.parseText(xml) ;
def n_id = xmldata1.record_id.text()
def n_number = xmldata1.'incident'.@number
def m_status    = xmldata1.incident.@status

assert n_id == '04707317-28e3-40cb-a227-15d2c91e08c2'


println(n_number)
println(m_status)
```

Comment: Might be worth pointing out that doing `@attribute` on a NodeList returns a list of attribute values. For the OP's problem I would use `xmldata1.incident[0].@number` to access the first element and get its attribute directly, else you're effectively doing a spread operation over all the Nodes and returning them as a list, which may be desirable, but (I suspect) not in this case.